# bash and bc math calculation with decimal point

Tags: bash, math, decimal-point, bc

I am trying to implement the following calculation within a Bash script using "bc" but the "scale" option is producing an incorrect result with 2 additional zeros at the end, which means that I am having to trim it manually (ugly).

Calculation:

((2592000-239)÷2592000)×100

Expected result: 99,990779321 (But I would like to show only 2 decimal places)

In Bash:

```
echo "scale=2; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

99.00

echo "scale=3; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

99.900

echo "scale=4; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

99.9900

echo "scale=5; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

99.99000

echo "scale=8; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

echo "scale=8; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

99.99077900

echo "scale=10; ((2592000-239)/2592000)*100" | bc

99.9907793200
```

According to the man page:

> NUMBERS
>          The most basic element in bc is the number.  Numbers are arbitrary precision numbers.  This precision is both in the integer
>   part and the fractional part.  All numbers are represented
>          internally in decimal and all computation is done in decimal.  (This version truncates results from divide and multiply operations.) 
>   There are two attributes of numbers,  the  length
>          and the scale.  The length is the total number of significant decimal digits in a number and the scale is the total number of
>   decimal digits after the decimal point.  For example:
>                  .000001 has a length of 6 and scale of 6.
>                  1935.000 has a length of 7 and a scale of 3.

Am I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
echo 'scale=2; 100*(2592000-239)/2592000' | bc -l

99.99
```

You're getting `99.00` because you're dividing first that gets `.99` and when it is multiplied with `100` it becomes `99.00` (due to `scale-2`)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want check your `bc` statements for the correct math-operations order, (the scale is applied for division) just let calculate `bc` using the default precision a format the output in `bash`, like:

```
printf "%.2f\n" $( bc -l <<< '((2592000-239)/2592000)*100' )
# 99.99
```